# Can I debug bluecove library?

Tags: java, debugging, open-source, bluetooth, bluecove

I see that [Bluecove](https://code.google.com/p/bluecove/) is open source, but there aren't any .pro files in sources. How can I open sources in eclipse and debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse you can right-click on project, and there is **Java Build Path**, there you have your dependencies.

Each dependency can be unfolded and there is "Source attachment", you can attach your source files there and then debug it.

Comment: Seems I can add only *.jar and *.zip files, but sources that I downloaded are in tar.gz archive. I change it to zip, but its not help.

Comment: Check whether in the zip files are properly stored, so that package folder (e.g. "org") is in the root of the archive.